# Is it possible to get values with C# from a dynamically added row with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, rows

I have a table and rows are added by users by clicking in a button. I do this with Javascript.
But then I have to get the values with C# and add then to database. C# is mandatory.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`AJAX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to get/send the values from and to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Now , I send them with ajax . How can I get the values in C# ? Response.Form ?

Comment: @lglifesgood - That's one option. You can use web services, webforms (with literal control), JSON. Pretty much anything that sends a response that you can parse in javascript (so JSON would be ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this would be to use AJAX. Since you're already using JavaScript, it would be a simple matter of adding the service call at the finalization stage of the action to implement the database changes directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479042.aspx

Comment: I have to use C# to insert values in the database . Thanks ;)

Comment: @lglifesgood: Right, so you write the web service or WCF service in C#, and the AJAX calls the web service. Or you can go the same page route and use the Asp.net/Ajax objects: http://www.asp.net/ajax

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using jquery & ajax
if you dont want you can put all new values in new rows in a hidden field (with a proper structure) and read hidden field value in server side